# ¿Como hago para darle una propiedad de tipo tag unica a mi boton generado de forma dinamica en mi datgridview mediante WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf

Actualmente relleno una tabla de forma dinámica sin problemas con información de una bd que tengo en sqlite pero agregue de manera dinámica una nueva columna que contenga botones y que servirán de actualizadores de los registros, el problema es que no se como acceder a esos botones ya que lo que quiero es ponerle una propiedad llamada tag y esa tag tomarla después de que hagan click en cada uno de los botones para que pueda identificarlo y así actualizar el indicado, pero la forma en que relleno mi nueva columna es tan simple que en ningún momento hago el llenado de mis atributos por separado lo cual me complica saber como hacer ese proceso.

Código donde agrego la nueva columna

```
    dataCode.Margin = new Thickness(5);
    dataCode.Width = 800;
    dataCode.MaxHeight = 200;
    DataGridTemplateColumn dgc = new DataGridTemplateColumn();
    DataTemplate dtm = new DataTemplate();

    FrameworkElementFactory btnReset = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(Button));
    btnReset.SetValue(Button.ContentProperty, "Actualizar");
    btnReset.SetValue(Button.ToolTipProperty, "Actualizar Fila");
    btnReset.SetValue(Button.TagProperty, "1");

    btnReset.AddHandler(Button.ClickEvent, new RoutedEventHandler(btnClickUpdate));

    dtm.VisualTree = btnReset;
    dgc.CellTemplate = dtm;
    dataCode.Columns.Add(dgc);
    dataCode.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
    dataCode.VerticalScrollBarVisibility = ScrollBarVisibility.Auto;
    dataCode.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility = ScrollBarVisibility.Auto;
```

Código de mi método que agrego a los botones

```
private void btnClickUpdate(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var keyword = (e.Source as Button).Tag.ToString();
    MessageBox.Show(keyword);
}
```

Comment: Para darte una respuesta dime si la PrimaryKey (que es la que iría en el Tag), la muestras en el DataGrid también? o la mantendrás oculta? --- y lo otro, no estás dispuesto a convertir la consulta (que devuelve una DataTable o DataSet) a una consulta que devuelva una lista de objetos? Eso te facilitaria las cosas enormemente.. aunque no estés usando MVVM.

Comment: @Leodev mantendre oculta el id de la tabla y antes intente hacer eso mismo de la lista de los objetos pero no me salio entonces lo intente de esta forma, pero igual estoy abierto a reintentarlo de la forma obtenerlo mediante una consulta e irlos agregando

Comment: Ok, entiendo, pero es muy complejo ponerle la PK como Tag a un botón si el DataGrid se llena directo con una consulta SQL.. Te daré una respuesta para cargar el DataGrid con una lista de objetos.

Answer (score 1):

En consecuencia al comentario que coloqué te dejo la respuesta para usar con una lista de objetos.

Primero: Para traer la consulta como una lista de objetos deberías poner en tu clase de conexión un método como este:

```
public List<Objetos> ListarObjetos()
{
    List<Objetos> lista = new List<Objetos>();
    string query = "SELECT ***********";

    using (SQLiteConnection con = new SQLiteConnection("MI CONNECTION STRING"))
    {
        using (SQLiteCommand com = new SQLiteCommand(query, con))
        {
            com.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure; //o Text si es un SELECT

            try
            {
                con.Open();
                SqLiteDataReader reader = com.ExecuteReader();
                if (reader.HasRows)
                {
                    while (reader.Read())
                    { 
                        Objeto o = new Objeto();
                        u.Id = Convert.ToString(reader["id"]);
                        u.Nombre = Convert.ToString(reader["nombre_objeto"]);

                        lista.Add(o);
                    }
                }

            }
            catch (SqlException ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
            }
        }
    }

    return lista;
}
```

Luego para llamar a ese método desde la clase donde llenas el DataGrid usas algo como esto:

```
private void CargarTabla()
{
    try
    {
        Task t = Task.Run(async () =>
        {
            MiListaDeObjetos = await Task.Run(() => MiConectorSQL.ListarObjetos());
            //asigno el ItemSource a través de Dispatcher sino dará error
            Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() =>
            {
                dataCode.ItemsSource = MiListaDeObjetos;
            }));

        });
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
    }
}
```

En el DataGrid agregas la columna con el botón directo como etiquetas XAML, las demás columnas se deberían rellenar solas al usar AutoGeneratingColumns=true

```
<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="True" DisplayIndex="10" CanUserAddRows="False" SelectionUnit="FullRow">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="EDITAR"  >
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Button Content="EDITAR" Click="OnEditClick"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns> 
</DataGrid>
```

Y cuando le des click al botón, que aparecerá en cada fila de forma automática, se debería lanzar un evento como esto:

```
private void OnEditClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Button button = (Button)sender;
    Objeto item = (Objeto)button.DataContext; 
    //El DataContext es el objeto que está representado en la fila completa 

    dataCode.SelectedItem = item;
    //esta linea es para que en el DataGrid se refleje la fila que seleccionas, porque al 
    //pulsar el botón no se selecciona, no es como clickear una celda.

    //Y así tienes el item con su PK y todos los datos
}
```

Ahora solo tendrías que adaptar los nombres de los objetos y tipos de dato para que coincidan.. si te fijas con esto no necesitas rebuscarte tanto con el uso de Tags y cosas raras, trabajar con objetos te facilita mucho más las cosas.

Ahora bien, podría ser todavía más sencillo si usaras el patrón MVVM, pero eso se puede obviar por el momento.

NOTA: Estoy algo oxidado con SqLite así que tal vez erré alguna declaración, pero espero haber sido claro.